# Combining std::views::take and pop_front pop_back

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

I can not figure out how to elegantly combine the `take` with action of removing the *taken* elements from container.

Consider the [following](https://godbolt.org/z/jzhz13zex) code:

```
static constexpr int kBatchSize = 4;
void fn(std::deque<int>& vals) {
    const auto elems = std::views::take(vals, kBatchSize);
    fmt::print("\n[");
    for (const auto& elem : elems) {
        fmt::print("{} ", elem);
    }
    fmt::print("]\n");

    for ([[maybe_unused]] const auto&_:elems) {
        vals.pop_front();
    }
}
```

It works fine(AFAIK) but I need to have an extra iteration since I can not figure out a way to combine taking of elements and removal.

note: `fmt::print` is just an example of logic per element, please do not focus on the fact that this could be done in a nicer way. In real code function is not a simple print.

Is there a elegant way to combine this into a single pass?

Comment: [You can format ranges directly.](https://godbolt.org/z/dEYPhP5rP) That said, I don't really understand the question.

Comment: So you want to pop n elements from the front of a `deck` and do something with those popped items, is that correct?

Comment: May we assume that you won't consider `vals.erase(vals.begin(), vals.begin() + kBatchSize);` acceptable either, because it would happen *after* to "taking"?

Comment: @Bob__  yes,yes         I dont like the manual nature of computing the begin  and end of to erase range, and I actually prefer current(slower for vector, probably also for deque) solution from readability perspective.

Comment: @Barry basically what Bob asked. I would like to do a take that modifies the unerlying container, eg. after taking 4 elements deque size is decreased by 4. And I would like to run some function for every element taken.

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl: Before the word `take` comes the word `views`. Which, as the name suggests, does not *modify* the range. It accesses it. Only operations on the container can modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were using Range-v3, you could loop on the `views::take(k)` and then `actions::drop(k)` afterwards, [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/hd34GMGzT):

```cpp
#include "fmt/format.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <range/v3/action/drop.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>
#include <ranges>

using ranges::actions::drop;
using std::ranges::views::take;

static constexpr int kBatchSize = 4;
void fn(std::deque<int>& vals) {
    fmt::print("\n[");
    for (const auto& elem : vals | take(kBatchSize)) {
        fmt::print("{} ", elem);
    }
    fmt::print("]\n");
    drop(vals, 4);
}

int main() {
    std::deque vals{1,2,3,4,5,6};
    fn(vals);
    fn(vals);
}
```

This doesn't really free you from having

> an extra iteration

but at least it hides it behind `ranges::actions::drop`, which tells very clearly what it does, given its name (*drop*s the elements) and the usage (*mutates* the input otherwise without `smth =`  on its left it would be a no-op).

---

If you want to

1. eventually mutate the `vals` parameter by removing some its leading elements,
2. but you also want do to something with those elements,

it's clear that you have to do 1 before 2, because those elements get destroyed, so you either

- operate on the elements and delete them one at a time,
- or you operate on all of them and then delete all of them.

The latter approach seems to be more straightforward and it's the one used by the proposed solutions (at least mine and Nicol Bolas'), which means you loop twice on those first elements. The former approach would be more complicated and just loop once instead of twice, which is not a big deal, I think.

Anyway, this is a solution which implements the first approach, looping only once:

```cpp
#include "fmt/format.h"

#include <range/v3/algorithm/for_each.hpp>
#include <range/v3/view/iota.hpp>
// the other include directives

using namespace ranges;
using namespace ranges::views;

static constexpr int kBatchSize = 4;
void fn(std::deque<int>& vals) {
    fmt::print("\n[");
    for_each(
        iota(0, std::min(kBatchSize, (int)vals.size())),
        [&vals](auto){
            fmt::print("{} ", vals.front());
            vals.pop_front();
        }
    );
    fmt::print("]\n");
}
```

However, consider that dropping elements one at a time with `.pop_front()` can be expensive for other containers (e.g. vector doesn't have it, but if it did, it would very expensive (and that's the reason why it hasn't such a member function)).

Beside this performance consideration, there's also another problem. To highlight it, let's if we can abstract out what you called `apply_drop`:

```cpp
void apply_drop(auto& vals, int n, auto f) {
    for_each(
        iota(0, std::min(n, (int)vals.size())),
        [&vals, f](auto){
            f(vals.front());
            vals.pop_front();
        }
    );
}
```

This does mostly what you meant, I hope. And `fn` would be implemented in terms of it like this:

```cpp
void fn(std::deque<int>& vals) {
    fmt::print("\n[");
    apply_drop(vals, kBatchSize, [](auto const& x){ fmt::print("{} ", x); });
    fmt::print("]\n");
}
```

But as you see I had to keep a few `print` statements in `fn` and couldn't bring them in `apply_drop`, because doing so would make no sense. Indeed, when in your comment you write

> provides a callback customization point.

I think you're referring to a callback function that is called for each element which you pop. And that cuts out the actions `fmt::print("\n[");` and `fmt::print("]\n");`, which have to be performed one off each, and in different moments; `fmt::print("{} ", x);` is the only thing that you are doing once per value, and so that's the only action that can be injected in the function that loops on the values (`apply_drop` in our case).

So your `fn` is not really simply "removing some leading elments and performing an action on each" (that's what `apply_drop` above does), but it's also doing other stuff that's not easy to shoehorn in the into `for_each` or another looping abstraction.

Comment: I see no reason why action::drop would not have an overload or similarly named twin that provides a callback customization point.  Like apply_drop that takes a lambda to run on element before it is dropped. Beside that nice answer, upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Views cannot modify containers; their job is to be a *view* of a range.

If you just want to iterate through the first X elements and then delete all of them (unless you want to copy those elements, it kinda has to be in that order), that's easily done with `std::for_each_n`:

```
void fn(std::deque<int>& vals)
{
    fmt::print("\n[");
    auto end_it = std::for_each_n(vals.begin(), kBatchSize, [](int const& elem){
        fmt::print("{} ", elem);
    });
    fmt::print("]\n");

    vals.erase(vals.begin(), end_it);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this *without* modifying `vals`. By converting the `vals` into a `subrange` and assigning each time to the `subrange`, for example:

```
#include <deque>
#include <ranges>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>

static constexpr int kBatchSize = 4;
auto fn(std::ranges::view auto vals) {
  const auto elems = std::views::take(vals, kBatchSize);
  fmt::print("{}\n", elems);

  return vals | std::views::drop(kBatchSize);
}

int main() {
  std::deque vals{1,2,3,4,5,6};
  auto res = fn(std::ranges::subrange{vals}); // [1, 2, 3, 4]
  res = fn(res); // [5, 6]
  res = fn(res); // []
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/dYn8o9cza)

The reason you can do this is that `std::views::take` and `std::views::drop` have specializations for `subranges` thanks to [P1739](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1739r4.html), i.e. they return a `subrange` of the correct size.

Comment: Very nice answer, although it technically does something else, so I need to clear the queue myself in the end. But very nice trick with taking range as argument, I never thought of that, upvoted.